# IQueryable OrderBy by Equal

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Is there a way to apply `OrderBy` on `IQueryable` starting by a specific value?

Ex: I have this follow entity

```
Name   | Age  | Type |
Marcos |  15  |  1   |
Andrew |  23  |  2   |
Phelip |  18  |  2   |
Jhonny |  14  |  3   |
```

I've tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
var result =  Query.OrderBy(x => x.Type == 2);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you explain _"it didn't work"_? Please provide your expected output and actual output so we can help get you to where you want to be.

Comment: Why do you have `x => x.Type == 2` should you just have `x => x.Type` instead?

Comment: Try `Query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Type == 2);` if you want the rows where `Type == 2` at the top.

Comment: Do you only want to display results that have `Type >= 2`?

Comment: What do you expect as an output: `1,2,2,3` or `2,2,1,3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the list ordered like `2,2,1,3`: all `2` records listed first, and the rest ordered normally.

This should do it:

```
var result =  Query.OrderBy(x => x.Type == 2 ? -1 : x.Type);
```

That will change the value that is used for ordering to `-1` when `Type` is `2`. Since `-1` is less than all of your other values, they will show at the top of the list.

If you are going to have records where the `Type` is `-1`, then you need to choose a different value. It has to be something that is less than all other values.

Comment: `Query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Type == 2).ThenBy(x => x.Type)` should also work.

Comment: @mm8 That's a better solution as it doesn't rely on a "magic" number that is less than all the expected values.